# How to convert string data having comma to a list in python

Tags: python

I have a string as below:

```
'["Product1, "Product1, Product2", "Product1, Product2, Product3", "Product3, Product4"]'
```

I want to convert this string into a list, but when I try to do this using `.split(",")` I am getting an list as below:

```
["Product1", "Product1", "Product2", "Product1", Product2", Product3", "Product3", "Product4"]
```

I would like to have a list as:

```
["Product1", "Product1, Product2", "Product1, Product2, Product3", "Product3, Product4"]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The list you claim to get isn't valid Python syntax. It's also not the result of `.split(",")`.

Comment: your input looks like JSON, so why don't you try the `json` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial list has `"` missing in first word.

We can use ast module in this case -

```
    import ast
    list1='["Product1", "Product1, Product2", "Product1, Product2, Product3", "Product3, Product4"]'
    
    list2=ast.literal_eval(list1)
    print(list2)
```

Other alternative would be to make use of json module

```
    import json
    list1='["Product1", "Product1, Product2", "Product1, Product2, Product3", "Product3, Product4"]'
    
    list2=json.loads(list1)
    print(list2)
```

Comment: json.loads(list1) worked liked a charm. Thank you so much for this